# Why does Blender make .dvd files when I tell it to make .mpg?

Tags: video

I rendered an animation as PNGs, then used Blender to make the PNGs into an .mpg. The output was a .dvd file.

I understand that if I rename the .dvd to .mpg, the video plays as I would expect. What I want to know is **why does Blender use this .dvd format, when it's seemingly identical to .mpg?**

Comment: @poor I know how to fix it; I want to know why it happens in the first place.

Comment: upload a .blend file?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your render settings?